# In Android Instamojo payment activity fails even after passing correct Order ID

Tags: android, instamojo

In Android Instamojo payment screen fails to build even after passing the correct order ID. The Order IDs generate works in the web URL but when I try to initialize the inbuilt Payment Activity of Instamojo, it instantly calls the on onInitiatePaymentFailure() with the error message "Error in getting order data." I am sure that I followed all the step mentioned in the read me about how to integrate the API correctly. (The app even has got all required permissions)

Error: {
"success": false,
"message": "Not found."
}

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem

I have also changed all test url to live url but then also i was facing this problem.

The problem was that I was using Testing Environment in android

I changed this line

```
Instamojo.getInstance().initialize(this, Instamojo.Environment.TEST);
```

to

```
Instamojo.getInstance().initialize(this, Instamojo.Environment.PRODUCTION);
```

Answer (score -1):

Issue is Solved.

Error due to the invalid order ID.

Comment: 32digit and 36 digit order id? what is the solution?

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Comment: I am getting 32 digit order ID and on both mobile and web, but it works on web and invalid on Mobil sdk.